# Why does an explicit interface implementation with varying case prevent a class from being CLS compliant?

Tags: c#, .net, case-sensitive, cls-compliant, cls

Consider the following example:

```
[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]

public interface I
{
    void FrobnicateSQL();
}

public class C : I
{
    public void FrobnicateSql() { }  // *
    void I.FrobnicateSQL() { }
}
```

The line marked with `*` yields the following compiler warning:

> CS3005: Identifier 'C.FrobnicateSql()' differing only in case is not CLS-compliant

Now, **I understand** that members *visible to other assemblies* [should not differ only in case](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/216356/33843), because, for example, case-insensitive languages such as VB.NET would not be able to decide which method to call.

And technically, yes, both members are visible and only differ in case, **but they are not visible at the same time**: Since `FrobnicateSQL` is an explicit interface implementation, it's only visible if the static type of the variable is `I`. The following VB code using the library above compiles correctly and is completely unambiguous:

```
Dim c As New C()
Dim i As I = c

c.FrobnicateSql()
i.FrobnicateSQL()
```

Still, the C# compiler treats this as a CLS violation. My question is: **Why?** Was it a deliberate design decision to include this rare edge case because it makes the specification and/or the algorithm for detecting CLS violations easier? Or did I miss something and the example above can actually cause problems in case-insensitive .NET languages?

Comment: In case you are wondering *"Why in the world would anyone do something like this?"*: We recently had such a case where some class A uses `FrobnicateSql`, class B uses `FrobnicateSQL` and *years later* we find out that it would be nice to have a common interface for both classes, but we do not want to break backwards-compatibility.

Comment: I think that is because maybe some languages could be case-insensitive. You can check https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_1st_edition_december_2001.pdf section 9 page 60

Comment: @MichaelMao: Indeed. However, I thought I already addressed this in my question...

Comment: The only thing I can think of, and it's obscure, is that while `private`, the method is still `virtual`, and hence visible to a derived class (not in C#, but on the IL level). In IL it's possible to override a private virtual method, and while explicit interface implementations are also `final` (so this can't legally be done), accessibility and visibility are different things. Even so, since a derived class can't legally do anything with the method that makes it visible even on the IL level (I think), this probably shouldn't count against CLS compliance.

Comment: Note that VB.NET makes it an *error* to have an explicit interface implementation and a public method differing only in case, notwithstanding that it can consume this C# type. Of course the semantics are different in both languages, since VB.NET allows you to name the explicit implementation while C# does not, and if VB.NET made it legal to call the implementation `I.FrobnicateSQL` it wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Rules are a lot easier to explain and interpret if they don't have to list cornercases.

Comment: "but they are not visible at the same time" -- well, sort of. Not to other classes etc, but as mentioned above, IL generates a virtual method. You can see this e.g. [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGAHbACmATgGYCGAxmQQJI4DeOBnByALAQGIUA9gCNiYOjXIBlAIoAZABQBKANw4Avjhz5uqAgGECIZmw5ddvAcLESpZaQEcIKgqwIbOAei8EAVOacVkwAdIKi4pIyCq7uWtgaQA=)